# Bad SQL syntax?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' DStormr', 'ddo.png', 'Online:' at line 1`

The sql is the following:

```
"UPDATE articulo SET '".$nombre."', '".$imagen."', '".$text."', '".$precio."', '".$popup."', ".$genero_id.
" WHERE id=".$id"";
```

What am I missing/not seeing?

Comment: SQL injection alert.

Comment: have you escaped your variables properly? What do you see if you echo the query instead of running it?

Comment: Suggest you read up on the format for SQL UPDATE statements, and then learn how to use prepared statements

Comment: Yes, this syntax is wrong. Why not to learn a proper one from one of numerous tutorials?

Comment: What is the data you're feeding into this code, anyway?

Comment: UPDATE <table> SET <columnname1>=<value1>, <columnname2>=<value2> WHERE <where condition>

Comment: Good God; there's *so many* terrible PHP tutorials out there.

Comment: You're missing all the `columname =` parts of the statement.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I'm testing this on my site and yes it was taken from a tutorial from the net...

Comment: Mark the tutorial as a bad one

Comment: Here's the PHP survival guide: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Comment: Thanks it was because i was missing the columname =  thing. And im saying that link as gold Mr Robert Harvey. Hope i get less noob with mysql within time...

Comment: I really wish there was a way to flag a question with a severe issue like XSS or SQL injection and it would automatically direct to a community-edited resource. It can feel like I'm trying to put out a forest fire with a watering can when coaching people on how to do things the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do an `UPDATE` you need to `SET key = 'value'`.

Comment: No, never. Use proper SQL placeholders like `?` or `:value` instead of this.